# finding an element between a tag and a list of tags using regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to find elements between two different tags but the catch is the first tag is constant but the second tag can be any tag belonging to a particular list.

for example a string

```
'TRSF BOOK TRANSFER CREDIT SND= abcd bank , 123  ORG= qwer123 OGB= qwerasd OBI= 123433'
```

I have a list of tags **['TRSF','SND=','ORG=','OGB=','OBI=']**

edit :  added the availability of '=' in the list itself

My output should look some what like this

```
TRSF : BOOK TRANSFER CREDIT 
SND : abcd bank , 123
ORG : qwer123
OGB : qwerasd
OBI : 123433
```

The order of tags, as well as the availability of the tags, may change also new tags may come into the picture

till now I was writing separate regex and string parsing code for each type but that seems impractical as the combination can be infinite

Here is what I was doing :

```
org = re.findall("ORG=(.*?) OGB=",string_1)
snd = re.findall("SND=(.*?) ORG=",string_1)
,,obi = string_1.partition('OBI=')
```

Is there any way to do it like

```
<tag>(.*?)<tag in list>
```

or any other method ?

Comment: It can only work if the list of tags is comprehensive. It looks like your tags may appear in any context, with and without `=` on the right, thus you must ensure the tag list is complete.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , good observation  assume that it is also included in the list , than what should be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tag list is complete, you can use a regex like

```py
\b(TRSF|SND|ORG|OGB|OBI)\b=?\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\b(?:TRSF|SND|ORG|OGB|OBI)\b|\Z)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kT94Gp/1). Details:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(TRSF|SND|ORG|OGB|OBI)` - a tag captured into Group 1
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `=?` - an optional `=`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*\b(?:TRSF|SND|ORG|OGB|OBI)\b|\Z)` - either end of string (`\Z`) or zero or more whitespaces followed with a tag as a whole word.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/cJWaD0):

```py
import re
s='TRSF BOOK TRANSFER CREDIT SND= abcd bank , 123  ORG= qwer123 OGB= qwerasd OBI= 123433'
tags =  ['TRSF','SND','ORG','OGB','OBI']
print( dict(re.findall(fr'\b({"|".join(tags)})\b=?\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\b(?:{"|".join(tags)})\b|\Z)', s.strip(), re.DOTALL)) )
# => {'TRSF': 'BOOK TRANSFER CREDIT', 'SND': 'abcd bank , 123', 'ORG': 'qwer123', 'OGB': 'qwerasd', 'OBI': '123433'}
```

Note the `re.DOTALL` (equal to `re.S`) makes the `.` match any chars including line break chars.

Comment: Thanks @wiktor , anytips on how to improve regex skills !

Comment: @Kaiser See [the bottom of this post of mine](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/wstribizew/my-regex-road-so-far).